# Get Onvif PTZ camera position

Tags: c#, camera, onvif

I need to know how can I retrieve the current camera position to know which are its X, Y and Z coordinates.
I know that a way to do this is to use getStatus() but it isn't available for all cameras (some models return 0,0,0).

There are any alternatives to know the current camera position? Now I'm using MediaService e PTZService libraries from onvif.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are other ways for getting the current position besides `getStatus()`. It's the only one I've been using so far.